# How to combine two pandas Dataframes with different timestamp densities?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have several pandas Dataframes `df1,df2,df3...` Each of them contains column of timestamps and column of respective values. For example:

df1:

```
2015-01-01T15:41:10.500Z, 9239.337890625
2015-01-01T15:41:50.543Z, 9539.337890625
2015-01-01T15:42:30.600Z, 8957.0458984375
2015-01-01T15:43:00.606Z, 8237.0458984375
```

df2:

```
2015-01-01T01:41:43.900Z, 67.58499908447266
2015-01-01T01:42:43.918Z, 67.58499908447266
2015-01-01T02:43:37.800Z, 67.58200073242189
2015-01-01T02:44:37.825Z, 67.58200073242189
```

I'm not sure if I put these into words correctly, so I need to combine these datafiles into one where there will be only one timestamp column and other columns will contain the measurement values. I'm thinking about something that would take the timestamp with the smallest increment and insert the other rows to their respective places. For the timestamp value that contains one measurement but not the other it will put Nan or keep it empty. 
The expected output would be something like this:

```
timestamp                 value1             value2 ...
2015-01-01T15:41:10.500Z, 9239.337890625 
2015-01-01T01:41:43.900Z,                    67.58499908447266
2015-01-01T15:41:50.543Z, 9539.337890625
2015-01-01T15:42:30.600Z, 8957.0458984375
2015-01-01T01:42:43.918Z,                    67.58499908447266
2015-01-01T15:43:00.606Z, 8237.0458984375
```

So how can I do this? Any suggestions or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are all the timestamps different?

Comment: Can u add an example of output?

Comment: HS-nebula, Timestamps are all in 2015-2016 interval, but their values are different.

Comment: Lucas Araújo, haven't written the code yet, I don't know necessary syntax and what to use

Comment: I think @LucasAraújo meant could you show us what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Also, are the timestamps indices or their own column?

Comment: I edited the post, thanks for mentioning

Comment: HS-nebula, I didn't understand what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the timestamps are their own column,

```
                    timestamp            value1
0    2015-01-01T15:41:10.500Z    9239.337890625
1    2015-01-01T15:41:50.543Z    9539.337890625
2    2015-01-01T15:42:30.600Z    8957.0458984375
3    2015-01-01T15:43:00.606Z    8237.0458984375
```

Use

```
df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ...], ignore_index = True)
df_all.sort_values(by='timestamp', inplace = True)
```

`ignore_index=True` tells `pandas` to forget the indexing in the original dataframes, and create new indexes based on the order in the new dataframe.

If the timestamps are the indices,

```
                                     value1
2015-01-01T15:41:10.500Z    9239.337890625
2015-01-01T15:41:50.543Z    9539.337890625
2015-01-01T15:42:30.600Z    8957.0458984375
2015-01-01T15:43:00.606Z    8237.0458984375
```

Use

```
df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ...])
df_all.sort_index(inplace = True)
```

The `sort_values` and `sort_index` will arrange the timestamps in chronological order.

Comment: HS-nebula, thanks a lot for your solution, It does what I want but the result contains values like:

`value1      value2  timestamp
 
133 9587.165039 NaN     2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z 

 0   NaN                0.14     2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z`

which have the same timestamp. How to join these rows so that they would become:

`value1      value2  timestamp

 9587.165039 0.14    2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking, but could you clarify it better by formatting what you want better? It sounds like you did have duplicate `timestamp` values after all. Also, use the @ symbol in front of a person's username to notify them.